# Why do we use the term syntax in computer languages and not the term grammar instead

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic

I am confused between the word syntax and grammar. Is there a reason that for computer languages we always use the word syntax to describe the word order and not the word grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term ["syntax"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) and ["grammar"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar) both comes from the field of linguistics. In linguistics, syntax refers to the rules by which sentences are constructed. Grammar refers to how the rules of the language relate to one another.

Grammar actually covers [syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax), [morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_(linguistics)) and [phonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonology). Morphology are the rules of how words can be modified to add meaning or context. Phonology are the rules of how words should sound like (which in turn govern how spelling works in that language).

So, how did concepts form linguistics got adopted by programmers?

If you look at really old papers and publications related to computing, for example Turing's seminal work on computability (Turing machines) or even older, Babbage's publications describing his Analytical Engine and Ada Lovelace's publications on programming, you'll find that they don't refer to computer programs as languages. Instead, they were just referred to as instructions or, if you want to get fancy, algorithms.

It was partly, perhaps mostly, the work of Noam Chomsky that related languages to programming.

Looking for a new way to study languages and how to extract meaning from sentences Chomsky created the concept of the [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy). His idea was to start with the simplest system that could process a string of "stuff" (sounds,letters,words): a Turing machine and categorize the instructions for a Turing machine as type-0 grammar. Then he went on to define grammar types 1, 2 and 3 (type 3 being the grammar of human languages such as English or Swahili) hoping that as we understand how complexity gets introduced we will end up with a parser for human languages.

Most programming languages are type 2. Indeed we have discovered parsers for types 0, 1 and 2 in the form of language interperters and CPU designs.

Inheriting Chomsky's work, we have defined "syntax" in computing to mean how symbols are arranged to implement a language feature and "grammar" to mean the collection of syntax rules.

Comment: Did a bit of googling and found that there was one programming language, that we can recognize today as a language (requires compiler or assembler to convert to machine instructions) was invented before Chomsky: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plankalk%C3%BCl. But the inventor of the language didn't use the term "language" for his programming language. He called it a "plan"

Answer (score 0):

Because a language has only "one" syntax (the set of strings it will accept), and probably very many grammars even if we exclude trivial variants.

This may be clearer if you think about the phrase, "the language syntax allows **stuff**".  This phrase is independent of any grammars that might be used to describe the syntax.